# Using jQuery with html without flashing <div>s

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, ajax

I have a page (index.php) that loads content from a seperate file (it.php) into a div using jQuery like so:

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jq.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    function loadTable(){
        $("#li1").load("it.php #segment1");
    }
    loadTable();
    setInterval(loadTable, 3000);
});
<div id="li1"></div>
```

it.php

```html
<div id="segment1">This text flashes and looks horrible when the page loads</div>
```

How can i make the whole page load at the same time? At the minute, the html and PHP loads before the jQuery which results in the div's content flashing on load.

I've tried everything but cannot seem to figure it out. I know that it can be done also, as I've seen websites loading dynamic content without it looking hideous.

Comment: If PHP is generating the page, and you're using jQuery to retrieve the other page (also PHP) why not skip the jQuery, and insert the content using the PHP you're already using?

Comment: Dynamic content. It's statistics being loaded in it.php....

Comment: Fair enough, then load the content into a hidden element and - once the data's loaded, and inserted - show the element?

Comment: That sounds like it's going to load slower than the rest of the page, which is what already happens.

Comment: Why? The content will load at the same speed, but without the "flashing" on loading the content; but, regardless, I'm not sure I see another option other than preloading the content before the user requests it.

Comment: it's not that it flashes per se. The whole page loads, and then the dynamic div elements load. It doesn't look too bad unless you click on a few links (which results in the whole page looking static except for the div elements which disappear and then reappear within miliseconds which catches your eye). I wish I could show you but it's on localhost WAMP server

Comment: A good example is on this page right here. If you click the logo (top left) see how the element at the top right loads slower than the rest of the page...

Comment: One pattern is to pre-allocate that space’s dimensions in CSS. You might not know it exactly, just a reasonable estimate. Then on load complete, add a class that animates it too 100%, maybe with some opacity or similar to be less jarring. Or, block the whole page with zero opacity until the AJAX is finished. Maybe throw some client-side caching in there, too.

Comment: If you do `<div id="li1"><?php include 'it.php'; ?></div>`, it should load the same file with the same content as if you load it using Ajax. If you then keep your JS, the only difference would be that the div contains the correct contents from the start (no flashing).

Comment: ugggh its like a strobe light when I navigate menu links. I have no idea what M.Eriksson suggested but that's certainly not working and throwing up tons of session start errors. Also, I know about making width and height set in CSS before page load.

Comment: _"I have no idea what M.Eriksson suggested"_ - Let me try again then; In your HTML, you have: `<div id="li1"></div>` which is the div you want to update, right? Since it's empty until your JS updates it, you will experience that "flash", as you say. All I suggest is to change `<div id="li1"></div>` to `<div id="li1"><?php include 'it.php'; ?></div>`. That's it. Why? Because then the div will contain the correct data from scratch instead of being empty.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do what you want.

One of the ways:

1. You may first hide the whole page (say enclose all the contents in a div known as `wholepagecontainer` which is hidden)
2. Then load the it.php into the DIV li1, then use callbackup to show the wholepagecontainer **on load complete**

So the code (based on what you post in your question) is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jq.js"></script>

<body>
<div style="display:none;" id="wholepagecontainer">
<div id="li1"></div>
.... other contents
</div>
</body>


<script>

function loadTable(){
$("#li1").load( "it.php #segment1", function() {
   $("#wholepagecontainer").show();
});
}

window.onload = function () {loadTable();}; 

</script>
```

[DEMO](https://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/23Ap2023/index.html)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but now the whole page strobes :'(

Comment: (1) Make sure you have removed the `setInterval(loadTable, 3000);` , and (2) please click the [DEMO] to see the effect (100% no strobes) -- I have included a big photo so that you can see the effect

Comment: Why not just include the file into the HTML directly instead? I don't see the value of using Ajax to load it here. It will just be an extra round trip to the server, slowing it down further before showing the page.

Comment: That demo is like a full blown emergancy flash. If the background (of the div) was blue, you could stick that on top of an ambulance!

Comment: If I load the file into the HTML directory and edit the values in the DB they don't automatically update on the page without using jQuery or refreshing the page.

Comment: @M.Eriksson, that's why I mentioned in the 1st line `There are a number of ways to do what you want` .

Comment: (1) @Ben, what DB ? You did not mention such thing in your original question.  (2) Please see the photo in my answer , I cannot see any ambulance

Comment: @Ben - You can still keep your JS that updates it every 3 seconds. The only thing including it in the HTML directly would do is setting the default contents of the div.

Comment: Ok. Well if that suggestion from M. Eriksson doesn't work I don't know if it's possible. I'm ideally after the whole page looking like it hasn't been reloaded when navigating manu links. Let me see if this works.

Comment: So I included the file but it's no different from just loaoding a segment in a div. It can be done as well, I've just gonne on youtube.com. See how when you navigate to shorts or any other link, the notification icon (which is obviously dynamic and updates periodically) doesn't flicker, or the rest of the page for that matter.

Comment: @Ben - _"but it's no different from just loaoding a segment in a div."_ - Of course not. That's all your JS is doing as well. The only difference is that it will be there from the start. To be honest, if that didn't help, then I have no idea what you're _actually_ asking about anymore. You need to take a step back and completely rephrase your question.

Comment: @Ben - Youtube (and other big apps like that) usually don't do things manually this way. They tend to use some frontend framework/tool, like vue, react, svelte, angular or similar. Those are tools you can build SPA's (Single Page Application) with, which is _very_ different from what you're doing here.

Comment: I wondered how long it would take to get a dislike. This site is rediculous. I've just got back into coding after like 15 years and ask a question, and that's what I get for not brown nosing the people who answer incorrectly...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQt-h753jHI